# Positioning an image with margin-top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

on this page http://lafon.atelier47.fr/domaines-interventions i need to positioning the image with circle using margin-top, on large desktop the positioning is ok but when the screen is smaller the positioning is not ok.
Perhaps there is a solution with css, javascript or jquery ?

My Code:

```
#qx-image-4919 {
    margin-top: -25%;   
}
```

Comment: Use media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best option here is to work with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). I don't know at which stage you want it to kick in. There are several ways to setup your media queries. Try to paste this in your CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #qx-image-4919 {
    margin-top: -25%; // your position when the screen is max 600px or smaller  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use media query** to change css values (in your case `margin-top`) of image to whatever value you want.

```
@media (max-width:1200px){

    #qx-image-4919 {
        margin-top: -70%;   
    }

}
```

This will change the margin-top to -70% for all device screens that are less than 1200 pixels

Read more about media queries here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

First try with

```
!important
```

Else,
Change your css code instead of % ;try with px

Like

```
margin-top: -200px !important;
```

---